# Laravel - can Omnipay use with other payment Gateway like revPay?

Tags: laravel-5, omnipay

currently our company is choosing the revPay as the payment Gateway.
Need to know is Laravel Omnipay able to be used for this revPay?

Answer (score 0):

The current list of omnipay gateways is here:

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

I do not see revPay on that list.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is my first time to integrate payment gateway using laravel framework. Is there any related tutorial that i can learn to integrate payment gateway in laravel?